# Spotify Web API Malformed json error when using /me/player/play endpoint

Tags: bash, spotify

I want to use the Spotify Web API to play a specfic song on one of my devices.
In the [dev article](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/start-a-users-playback/) it says to use a JSON Array. I tried doing it like this:

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play"
-H "Authorizatin: Bearer {authToken}"
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
--data "json={\"uris\": [\"spotify:track:0i2QIV9Lku6x5zQkN7DZpn\"]}"
```

However, I am getting a 400 error code:

```
{
"error" : {
"status" : 400,
"message" : "Malformed json"
}
```

If anyone could tell me how I have to send this request, that'd be great.

Comment: If you're sending JSON data, shouldn't you set the Content-Type to `application/json` and  send data as `{ /* json here */ }`, not `json={/* json here */}`? Is this a Spotify-specific way of cURL-ing JSON?

Comment: Replace your last two parameters with this `-H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"uris": ["spotify:track:0i2QIV9Lku6x5zQkN7DZpn"]}'`

Comment: Actually it worked just by removing the `json=` from the request body and not changing anything else. Thanks for pointing that out though.